# Remove From Array PHP in Foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a php foreach loop that is displaying all my products on my store. The code looks like this:

```
 <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>

// getting products here

<?php } ?>
```

There are some products I wish not to show up in that loop, that I have the id's for, so I edited the Foreach loop like this:

```
<?php $ids = array(564,365,66,234,55); ?>

<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
    <?php if(in_array($product['product_id'],$ids)) { ?>
          //getting products here
        <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This did just the opposite of what I wanted to do. I kinda knew it would. But I figured there is some way to reverse this and hide only those products. I was wondering if there was away to remove those products ids from the product array, and then continue the php loop getting all the other products. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually want to remove the elements from the array, or just not display them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply negate the condition:

```
if(!in_array($product['product_id'],$ids))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the logical NOT operator, `!` to only execute your code if the ID is NOT in the list.

```
<?php $ids = array(564,365,66,234,55); ?>

<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
    <?php if(!in_array($product['product_id'],$ids)) { ?>
         // do operation
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the !

So we are saying if the ids are not in the array it's cool to display them.

```
<?php $ids = array(564,365,66,234,55); ?>
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
<?php if(!in_array($product['product_id'],$ids)):?>
  //show products that are not in array
<?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on working with this reduced set later, you could use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter).

```
$filtered = array_filter($products, function($x) use($ids) { 
    return !in_array($x['product_id'], $ids); 
});

foreach ($filtered as $product) {
    // do operation
}
```